# Exewrap / JSmooth等のEXE生成ツールがメモリをかなり使う

Tags: java, maven

exewrap / JSmoothについて

javaでexeファイルを作成しようと、
これから作ろうとしているものに必要な依存関係をmavenで取り込んで、
maven-assembly-pluginでfat-jarビルドし、
java -jarで実行可能なファイルを作成しました。

今のところHello worldを作っただけですが、mavenで取り込んだ依存ライブラリが重く、
jarファイルが19Mになってしまいました。

その後動作を確認して、exewrapだったりJSmoothなりでラッピングしてみたんですが、
ラッピング実行の際OutOfMemoryが発生して100%落ちます。

そもそもjavaでWindowsアプリケーションを作ろうというのが愚行かもしれませんが、
やはりC++なりなんなりで作るべきでしょうか？
8G中6G与えても足らなかったので、現在のリソースではできないのかなと思いました。
これを試してみたら？というのがあったらおしえてください。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JDK7 update6 以降ならば JDK 自体に javafxpackager (JDK8u20 以降は javapackager) というアプリケーションパッケージングのためのツールがバンドルされており、インストール可能なパッケージをビルドできるようになっています。
(Windows の場合は予め Inno Setup か WiX をインストールしておく必要があります)

名前に JavaFX と入っていますが、どの Java アプリケーションに対してもパッケージングを行うことができます。

以下に詳細な日本語の解説ドキュメントがありますので、参照してください。かなりの分量ですが、1 から 10 章までは目を通しておくことをお勧めします (自己完結型パッケージについては 7 章で解説されています) 。
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/